# Create a tag during a release pipeline in azure-devops

Tags: azure-devops

**Setup**

When running a release pipeline, i do

1. consume a artifact of build-pipeline projectA ( which uses the repository projectA )
2. this artifact is a node package build
3. I  will inject (re-version) the package version ( using a pipeline variable `VERSION` ) and then release to the npm registry as the final step

**Goal**
Beside all the build / release tasks work, we have one specific issue, and that is the missing `checkout of the repository` in the release step. We do not want to have the repository for actually "rebuilding" something, but for tagging the commit we build using the variable `$VERSION` and pushing it the the repository.

**Issue**

I do know how to get the `commit hash` of our source project repository build ( env var `Build.SourceVersion` ) and the repository name ( env var `Build.Repository.Name` ), but i do not understand how i actually would get the repository checked out since i miss the credentials.

Right now i have the repository on Github ( private repository ), might though also move to a private Bitbucket.

The actual concrete question is, how would one checkout the repository with

- either using a static name
- or using `Build.Repository.Name`

And with

- either a generic task ( some git repo )
- or a specific SCM repo task ( like `checkout-from-github` or `checkout-from-bitbucket` using some sort of service connection ).

I assume i need some sort of credentials, in my current case it would be some sort of Github access token or similar ( oAuth )?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So I am not sure if you are using GUI based Releases or the newer [multi-stage pipeline feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/multi-stage-pipelines-experience?view=azure-devops).

For the classic release GUI you can add an Artifact that is your Github repository from the [release definition editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops#sources). When you go to add the Artifact it will ask you to configure the service connection back to github, or you can use an existing connection.

In the release definition editor at the Agent Job level, you will want to be sure to check the **Allow scripts to access the OAuth token**

[image]

From there navigate to the release directory that contains your repository and then you can push a tag.

```
cd $(Agent.ReleaseDirectory)\_enufacas_azureDevOps.Postman
git tag  Rel-$(Build.BuildNumber)
git push --tags
```

The multi-stage pipeline also has a similar path using the [checkout task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#checkout)

Comment: This is even more then asked, thank you a lot! I was not get aware of the multistage pipelines, will look into those too!

Comment: @EugenMayer No problem!

Comment: Thanks, very useful! You can avoid the cd command by setting the working directory under the Advanced options :)

Answer (score 0):

There were additional steps to interact with the git repo in my instance. I managed to automate tag creation to the commit of an associated build artifact with the following:

**New command prompt or PowerShell script task**

(Working directory = $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/{source-alias}/)

```
git config --global user.email "pipeline@companyemail.com"
git config --global user.name "Azure DevOps Pipeline"
git init
git remote add origin https://$(System.AccessToken)@dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_git/{repo-name}
git fetch origin {branch-name}
git tag -a {new-tag-name} $(Release.Artifacts.{source-alias}.SourceVersion) -m "new-release"
git push origin {new-tag-name}
```

- {source-alias} = DevOps' Artifacts' source alias (usually has an underscore prefix)

[image: artifact source alias]

- $(System.AccessToken) = System variable in all release pipelines. Make sure you've set **Allow scripts to access the OAuth token** on the Agent job so this is populated
- {organization} = your DevOps' organisation
- {project} = your DevOps' project
- {repo-name} = your DevOps' repository name
- {branch-name} = name of the git branch you're adding a tag to
- {new-tag-name} = name of the tag you'd like to add to the build's latest commit
- $(Release.Artifacts.{source-alias}.SourceVersion) = System variable to obtain the git commit from your release artifact for this specific build

**In my instance, setting the git origin with a PAT token $(System.AccessToken) was important to overcome auth issues with git.**

I also had to grant specific git privileges to the DevOps' build user. Accessed via Project settings -> Repositories -> {repo-name} -> Security - then selecting "Project Collection Build Service ({project})", and setting "Allow" on:

- Contribute
- Create tag
- Read

**Note**: I had two users with similar names:

- Project Collection Build Service
- Project Collection Build Service {project}

I had to assign the privileges to the latter, the user which included the name of my project in brackets

*Screen to apply security settings currently looks as below (this is not showing the correct user to apply to)*

[image: security screen]