# Tag a commit in Git based on an Azure release pipeline

Tags: git, azure-devops

I want to view my Git main branch and see at a glance what commit has been deployed to my UAT or PROD environment.

I want to use git tags to visualize this with the environment name(s) beside a particular commit.

An Azure build pipeline creates an artifact when a commit occurs to the main. However, the Azure release pipeline UAT and PROD stages will be run manually.

What is a good approach to automate the tagging (with the environment name UAT or PROD) of the commit in the main associated with the build artifact that actually got deployed?

Comment: You can use Azure tags 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/git-tags?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser

Then you can filter the tag in azure pipeline as a trigger

Comment: "Best" questions are invariably a matter of opinion; you might want to reword the last sentence.

Comment: do you use yaml or classic pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for [Create a tag during a release pipeline in azure-devops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59954530/create-a-tag-during-a-release-pipeline-in-azure-devops) ... I couldn't figure out how to do this from a ***release*** pipeline and so was looking to see if there were better approaches.