# How to tag an Azure DevOps Release automatically

Tags: azure-devops, tags, azure-devops-rest-api

I didn't found any answer to my question on StackOverflow or in the @Microsoft Azure DevOps official documentation so I will try with this post.

I am using the Releases in Azure DevOps to do deployment but I would like to add some tags to each Release **dynamically and automatically during the deployment (using a Powershell or Bash script)** but I can't find anyway to do that.

To be clear, I am not talking about GIT tags or Builds tags. I want to add tags here:

[image: Tags column]

Using the web portal, I can manually add a tag here by going there:

[image: Creating tags manually]

[image: Tag created manually]

As you can see, it can be created manually.

So, as it is possible to do that manually and that [it is possible to do that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#addbuildtag-add-a-tag-to-the-build) in the Builds (YAML) using the command just below. I imagine it's possible to do the same for Releases

> ##vso[build.addbuildtag]build tag

On this same documentation, it is not explained how to do that for the Releases.

Moreover, I tried to use the [Azure DevOps API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/update-release?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP):

```
PUT https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}?api-version=7.0
```

But when I edit the "tags" property and send the PUT request, it just does nothing and returns the response with the tags I sent.
Here is my API try using POSTMAN:

[image: API POSTMAN Try]

Do any of you have any ideas on how to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 1):

Rest API can not update the release tags. I`ve registered the bug:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Rest-API-does-not-update-release-tags/10426047

Maybe it will be available in the future.

Comment: I just upvoted your post and added a comment. Thank you for your answer/contribution.

Answer (score 0):

As for of my knowledge, it is not possible to add dynamic tags in Azure DevOps classic release pipelines.

Your use-case can be achieved in YAML pipelines. For that, you can use this reusable template :

```yaml
# step-add-tag.yaml
parameters:
  - name: tag

steps:
  - bash: |
      echo "##vso[build.addbuildtag]${{ parameters.tag }}"
    displayName: Add "${{ parameters.tag }}" tag
```

```yaml
# azure-pipelines.yaml
stages:
  - stage: build
    jobs:
      [...]

  - stage: deploy_prod
    displayName: Deploy PROD
    condition: succeeded() # start only if build succeed
    dependsOn: build # do not start until build finished
    lockBehavior: sequential # run one after the other
    jobs:
      - job: my-app
        displayName: My App
        steps:
          - checkout: self
            displayName: Checkout sources

          - template: step-add-tag.yaml
            parameters:
              tag: env-prod

          - run: |
              [script or infrastructure as code to deploy your app]
```

You can extend to:

- A separated template for deployments. Template would take `env` and `instance` parameters. Tag can be dynamically applied, with for example `env-prod` and `instance-europe` to your pipeline execution.
- A dashboard summarizing your deployments per environment, or per instance.

Screenshot of a real-life example using a separated template for deployments:

[successful pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nFSk.png)

[failed pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foJOC.png)

I use YAML pipelines 100% of the time, and I recommend doing so because of:

- The usage of Git allows you to apply **quality controls** and audit on your code
- In case of a disaster, **pipelines are self-supporting**, thus can be re-started anywhere
- YAML templates can be separated into **modules to centralize knowledge** and specific enterprise integrations. Imagine a pipeline named “java-spring-container” which would include static tests, vulnerabilities test, test archiving, container building, tagging, dynamic penetration tests, integration tests. Templates can be shared and managed as inner-source projects in your organization.

Related blob posts:

- https://piotr.gg/dev-ops/add-tag-to-you-build-in-azure-devops.html
- [Create a tag during a release pipeline in azure-devops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59954530/create-a-tag-during-a-release-pipeline-in-azure-devops)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/add-tags-to-work-items?view=azure-devops

Comment: Hello @Clémence, thanks for your answer.
Unfortunately, using YAML can't solve our problem.
We already use YAML to create deployment artifacts that we then use in Azure Releases. The tags actually work well there.

Nevertheless, we are forced to use Releases because we need the approval system present in Releases. 
Manual approvals during YAML pipelines are too short to be usable.

So we'd really like a solution for tagging our Releases so we can sort them easily (because there are a lot of them!).

Note that we use TASK GROUPS in releases to separate them, as you suggest in YAML.